# mapbox Add Navigation Dependencies

Tags: android, navigation, dependencies, mapbox

I'm attempting to follow the mapbox tutorials for the [Navigation API.](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/navigation/overview/)

In my app build.gradle I've added:

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.11.1'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.11.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

But the gradle build could not resolve. What is the situation? I thought all I needed was to add the dependencies block and it would acquire the dependency. I've already set my proxy settings. It acquires the other mapbox dependencies.

Error Message: 
Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

> Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.11.1.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.11.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-navigation/0.11.1/mapbox-android-navigation-0.11.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-navigation/0.11.1/mapbox-android-navigation-0.11.1.pom'.
>   dl.google.com
>   Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.11.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-navigation/0.11.1/mapbox-android-navigation-0.11.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-navigation/0.11.1/mapbox-android-navigation-0.11.1.pom'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com
>   Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.11.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-navigation/0.11.1/mapbox-android-navigation-0.11.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-navigation/0.11.1/mapbox-android-navigation-0.11.1.pom'.
>   maven.google.com

Comment: Please include as much of the error messages as possible.

Comment: Updated with error output

Comment: Update: It looks like the Mapbox Services dependency is wrong as well. Adding implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:3.0.0-beta.4' as described in https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/mapbox-services/overview/ does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
// You Can Use This Lib. For Android Studio 3.0.1


    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.9.0'
    implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.9.0') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.3.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

// It's Including Basic Needed Dependencies

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.36'
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
```

// build.gradle

```
// RX
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.10'

//Network
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0'

// GSON
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

// LifeCycle
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0'

// Navigatiopn
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha03"

/// navigation component
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5"

// Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.37"
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.36'
```